# Create a hexagonal grid around coordinate to find max exposure

Tags: trigonometry

I have a table of locations with monetary values and lat/lngs in Sql Server. When I add a new location I want to calculate the largest sum product $ of locations values within a 200m radius using sql (know how to do this bit). The first circle would be the new location's lat/lng, but then I would like to move the circle around in 50m increments (up to 200m away), to find the max exposure circle. I think I would create a hexagonal grid. But I've been stuck on how to do this for a long time. My math skills are very poor, so a laypersons explanation would be really helpful.

Once I got the hexagonal points I was going to adapt and feed them into this (I know there will be some inaccurcy):

```
Declare @Lat  float = 51.500709
Declare @Lng  float = -0.124646
Declare @LatM float = -50
Declare @LngM float = 0

Select OldLat = @Lat
      ,OldLng = @Lng
      ,NewLat = @Lat + @LatM/111111
      ,NewLng = @Lng + @LngM/(111111 * cos(radians(@Lat)) )
```

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. Circles close packed in a hexagonal grid will leave some points uncovered. Or are you saying each hexagon is circular enough? What if centering a circle not at a grid point does better? If you post pictures of several configurations showing the answer you expect in each case we might be able to help. (If your rep is too low to post the pictures, post a link and someone here will paste them in.)

Comment: Searching for _hexagonal grid qgis_ may help. So may this https://gist.github.com/grischard/f644d467fbe5052c1ca8f97f5008c4f8

Comment: Thank you that's helpful. This question (link below) is what I am asking with the diagram shown. I would place the circle (200m radius) in the center of each hexagon. I could then decrease the size of the hexagons to place more circles, but the circle radius would stay the same. As you say this might not get the highest exposure circle, but I am happy with this granularity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52256593/polar-coordinates-of-vertices-of-a-hexagonal-grid